# Within a specific view function Regardless of the login status, request.user = AnonymousUser. Is there a way to fix it?

Tags: django

There was a problem testing the password change function. Thank you for watching!

Feed view works normally

git : https://github.com/hyunsokstar/hyun4/blob/master/nomadgram/nomadgram/images/views.py

so
request.user = allieus (login user)

```
class Feed(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        user = request.user
        following_users = user.following.all()
        print("following_users , ", following_users)
        image_list = []
        for following_user in following_users:
            user_images = following_user.images.all()[:2]

            for image in user_images:
                print("image : ", image)
                image_list.append(image)

        # 본인 이미지도 추가
        my_images = user.images.all()[:2]
        for image in my_images:
            image_list.append(image)

        print("image_list : ", image_list)

        sorted_list = sorted(image_list, key=get_key, reverse=True)
        serializer = serializers.ImageSerializer(sorted_list, many=True)

        # return Response(status=200)
        return Response(serializer.data)

def get_key(image):
    return image.created_at
```

but

request.user of ChangePassword is always printed for AnonymousUser 
so An error occurred when trying to change the password.

If you know why and If you know how to fix it Thank you very much!

github :
https://github.com/hyunsokstar/hyun4/blob/master/nomadgram/nomadgram/users/views.py

```
class ChangePassword(APIView):
    def put(self, request, username, format=None):
        print("함수 실행 확인(ChangePassword) ")
        user = request.user
        print('user : ', user)
        current_password = request.data.get('current_password',None)

        if current_password is not None:
            # request로 넘어온 비밀번호와 db의 비밀번호를 비교
            passwords_match = user.check_password(current_password)

            # 비밀번호가 정확할 경우 새로운 비밀번호를 request로부터 가져와서 user 객체에 save
            if passwords_match:
                new_password = request.data.get('new_password',None)
                if new_password is not None:
                    user.set_password(new_password)
                    user.save()
                    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                # None일 경우 400 응답
                else:
                    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            # false일 경우 400 응답
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        # None일 경우 400 응답
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the username to get User, i.e

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ChangePassword(APIView):
    def put(self, request, username, format=None):
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)  # This will return user
```

Comment: It was a little hard for me. The problem was easily resolved. Are you a genius? Thank you Adaikalaraj !

Comment: From my experience i gave my suggestion, You can mark it correct if you find it helpful.